# ArrayFormula displays dates improperly. How can I fix this?

Tags: google-sheets

Form Responses 1 looks like this: 6/1/2020 13:59:11
On my second sheet, it turns it into this: 43983.582763588

This is the formula I'm using:

```
=ArrayFormula(('Form Responses 1'!A2:A&" "))
```

What's going on here?! :| Please help. I've tried converting to plain text on Response Sheet 1 and it fixed it temporarily. However, new entries still turn into the weird format.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the `&" "` part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

*Days are stored in Google Sheets as the number of days since 1<sup>st</sup> January 1900. You just need to change your Sheet's display format and remove the `&" "`.*

#### Fix:

Change your formula to the following:

```
=ArrayFormula(TO_DATE('Form Responses 1'!A2:A))
```

Then, highlight the column for which this Arrayformula will enter data, follow the `Format > Number > More formats > More date and time formats` and fill out the opened modal to look like this:

[image]

Using the dropdown arrow on the right (`v`) to select each of the `Month/Day/Year Hour:Minute:Second` elements you like.

Afterwards your dates should look like this:

[image]

Comment: hrmmm it kind of works. However, where there is no new wntry, i'm flooded with #VALUE! errors indicating: "function INT parameter 1 expects number values but '' is a text and cannot be coerced to a number." Also, there's no more time, just date. any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Why do you have the `&" "`? Why can't you just use `=ArrayFormula('Form Responses 1'!A2:A)`?

Comment: It didn't. Now it's showing 12/30/1899 for all empty cells, and time isn't included. Do you know how to include time? is there some sort of TO_DATE & time.

Comment: You need to change the display format of the range - I've updated my answer.

Comment: Do you know how to get it to work with this?
=ArrayFormula(TO_DATE(trim('Form Responses 1'!AG2:AG&" "&'Form Responses 1'!AH2:AH)))

Comment: @t0m3k Throw it up as a new question [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) as it needs more explanation than in a comment :)

Comment: Done https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62175732/unable-to-use-to-date-with-multiple-columns-merging-in-google-sheets Thank you!