# Unable to use TO_DATE with multiple columns merging in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Prior question:

[ArrayFormula displays dates improperly. How can I fix this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62171540/arrayformula-displays-dates-improperly-how-can-i-fix-this/62172790?noredirect=1#comment109964151_62172790)

Modified formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(TO_DATE(trim('Form Responses 1'!AG2:AG&" "&'Form Responses 1'!AH2:AH)))
```

The solution doesn't work when there are multiple columns merging. Any idea how to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(IF('Form Responses 1'!AG2:AG=0,"",TEXT('Form Responses 1'!AG2:AG,"mm/dd/yyyy HH:MM "))&'Form Responses 1'!AH2:AH))`

Adjust the date time format as you like (check help on TEXT function)

Comment: I used this and it works! =ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT('Form Responses 1'!AG2:AG,"")&TRIM('Form Responses 1'!AH2:AH)) 

Thank you!

Comment: That's what date 0 means.  Why do you have blanks?  (But I added the check)